# emmip - is there a way to plot a 'merged' treatment x time factor?

Tags: r, longitudinal, emmeans

I have attached some published data (at the end) that comes from a link on:

https://www.middleprofessor.com/files/applied-biostatistics_bookdown/_book/pre-post.html

I can run a fairly standard linear mixed model with treatment, time and a treatment x time interaction and get the same results:

```
# LDA (mixed model)----
> m3 <- lme4::lmer(y ~ treat*time + (1|id), data = dat)
> summary(m3) 
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: y ~ treat * time + (1 | id)
   Data: dat

REML criterion at convergence: 263.3

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.7804 -0.5552  0.1779  0.6036  1.2683 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept) 26.57    5.155   
 Residual             46.49    6.819   
Number of obs: 40, groups:  id, 20

Fixed effects:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)           54.656      2.849  19.182
treatil_17             2.472      3.842   0.644
timepost              -1.155      3.214  -0.359
treatil_17:timepost   11.712      4.334   2.702

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) trt_17 timpst
treatil_17  -0.742              
timepost    -0.564  0.418       
trtl_17:tmp  0.418 -0.564 -0.742
```

and plot the results nicely using emmip:

```
> emmeans(m3, revpairwise ~ treat | time)
$emmeans
time = pre:
 treat emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 veh     54.7 2.85 31.8     48.9     60.5
 il_17   57.1 2.58 31.8     51.9     62.4

time = post:
 treat emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 veh     53.5 2.85 31.8     47.7     59.3
 il_17   67.7 2.58 31.8     62.4     72.9

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
time = pre:
 contrast    estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
 il_17 - veh     2.47 3.84 31.8   0.644  0.5245

time = post:
 contrast    estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
 il_17 - veh    14.18 3.84 31.8   3.692  0.0008

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 

> emmip(m3, treat ~ time) +
+   geom_point() +
+   geom_line(size = 1) +
+   scale_y_continuous(limits = c(50, 70), breaks = seq(50, 70, by = 2)) + 
+   theme_bw(base_size = 15)
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

[image]

I now want to run a constrained version of the model essentially forcing the main effect for group to be equal to 0. To do this, I followed the steps to 'merge' the treatment and time factors into one with a common baseline level and then new levels for each post treatment (page 12 at the following link):

https://bendixcarstensen.com/Notes/rm.pdf

```
# CONSTRAINED LDA (mixed model) ----
# Create a 'merged' treat*time variable with 3 levels:
# - a common pre level for both treatments
# - a new post level for each treatment
dat <- transform(dat, treat_time = Epi::Relevel(interaction(treat, time), list(baseline = 1:2)))
# Inspect levels
with(dat, ftable(treat, time))
with(dat, ftable(treat_time, treat, time))

> m4 <- lme4::lmer(y ~ treat_time + (1|id), data = dat)
> summary(m4)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: y ~ treat_time + (1 | id)
   Data: dat

REML criterion at convergence: 268.2

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.7986 -0.5202  0.1392  0.6089  1.2810 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept) 25.74    5.074   
 Residual             46.02    6.784   
Number of obs: 40, groups:  id, 20

Fixed effects:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)            56.016      1.894  29.571
treat_timeveh.post     -2.027      2.902  -0.698
treat_timeil_17.post   11.270      2.676   4.212

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) trt_t.
trt_tmvh.ps -0.419       
trt_tml_17. -0.454  0.190


> emmeans(m4, revpairwise ~ treat_time)
$emmeans
 treat_time emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 baseline     56.0 1.89 32.9     52.2     59.9
 veh.post     54.0 2.79 37.0     48.3     59.6
 il_17.post   67.3 2.53 36.9     62.2     72.4

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
 contrast              estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
 veh.post - baseline      -2.03 2.97 24.2  -0.684  0.7752
 il_17.post - baseline    11.27 2.72 22.8   4.141  0.0011
 il_17.post - veh.post    13.30 3.72 32.5   3.573  0.0031

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates 

> emmip(m4, ~ treat_time) +
+   geom_point() +
+   geom_line(size = 1) +
+   scale_y_continuous(limits = c(50, 70), breaks = seq(50, 70, by = 2)) + 
+   theme_bw(base_size = 15)
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
>
```

[image]

But I don't know how (or if there's a way) of producing a similar plot using emmip, given the factor levels are combined. I would like to be able to essentially reproduce the first plot above showing the change for each group from the common baseline. I guess I can do this manually in ggplot - just wondered if there was some way of doing it with emmip straight out of the box?

```
dat <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 
19L, 20L, 20L), treat = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("veh", "il_17"), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("pre", "post"), class = "factor"), 
    y = c(63.9871851, 62.7837203, 58.4825871, 59.4795929, 59.7735716, 
    42.4923719, 51.0754017, 55.5395164, 55.8808155, 42.8811745, 
    38.686015, 40.6969206, 46.8213372, 61.6, 62.6084263, 62.987013, 
    54.5901379, 53.0518311, 60.99353, 65.8177226, 66.2765671, 
    77.6594363, 60.1260258, 80.5687204, 49.444707, 63.7658228, 
    55.1138485, 77.6594363, 61.4070066, 80.5687204, 52.4932976, 
    49.444707, 55.1138485, 57.5908965, 61.4070066, 54.4305875, 
    52.4932976, 68.6955215, 53.5461576, 68.3395943), treat_time = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("baseline", 
    "veh.post", "il_17.post"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-40L))
```

Comment: Did you try`emmip(m3, ~ treat * time)`?

Comment: Thanks Russ, but I'm wanting to do this for m4 which has a 3 level factor variable (baseline, veh.post, il_17.post). There may not be an easy way to do it.

Comment: I don't even see how you could do it manually. You have 3 means that are some function of the four means you started with, and so you have lost a degree of freedom's worth of information about those four original means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess if you are using the same baseline value for each treatment, you can do something like this:

```
foo = emmeans(m4, "treat_time")
bar = contrast(foo, list(b1 = c(1,0,0), p1 = c(0,1,0), 
                         b2 = c(1,0,0), p2 = c(0,0,1)) )
levels(bar) = list(time = c("baseline", "post"), 
                   treat = c("veh", "il_17") )
emmip(bar, treat ~ time)
```

#### simpler way

I discovered you can greatly simplify the second step:

```
foo = emmeans(m4, "treat_time")
bar = foo[c(1,2,1,3)]
levels(bar) = list(time = c("baseline", "post"), 
                   treat = c("veh", "il_17") )
emmip(bar, treat ~ time)
```